# List files in R that do NOT match a pattern

Tags: regex, r

`R` has a function to list files in a directory, which is `list.files()`. It comes with the optional parameter `pattern=` to list only files that match the pattern.

Files in directory `data`:
`File1.csv File2.csv new_File1.csv new_File2.csv`

```
list.files(path="data", pattern="new_")
```

results in `[1] "new_File1.csv" "new_File2.csv"`.

But how can I invert the search, i.e. list only `File1.csv` and `File2.csv`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I belive you will have to do it yourself, as `list.files` does not support Perl regex (so you couldn't do something like `pattern=^(?!new_)`).

i.e. list all files then filter them with `grep`:

```
grep(list.files(path="data"), pattern='new_', invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

The `grep(...)` does the pattern matching; `invert=TRUE` inverts the match; `value=TRUE` returns the values of the matches (i.e. the filenames) rather than the indices of the matches.

Comment: Is it possible to do a similar method but with matching multiple patterns?

Answer (score 10):

I think that the simplest (and probably fastest if you include programmer time) approach is to run `list.files` 2 times, once to list all the files, then the second time with the pattern of files that you do not want, then use the `setdiff` function to find those file names that are not in the group that you want to exclude.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @Greg Snow answer:

```
library("here")
path <- here("Data", "Folder", "Subfolder")

all_files <- list.files(path, pattern = ".csv")
unwanted <- list.files(path, pattern = "_unwanted.csv")
wanted <- base::setdiff(all_files, unwanted)
```