# List files NOT containing a specific string in list.files using R

Tags: r

In a directory files are listed as in the format `DDW-xxxxB-28.xlsx`, where the `xxxx` is a 4 digit number. I'm trying to **not** select the file containing 4 zeros in that place. How to make this happen while passing the pattern in `list.files` function?

Comment: I'm not that it's what you want. `lf=list.files('.',pattern='...'); lf=lf[-which(stringr::str_detect(lf,'-0000B-')==T)]`. Do you want to pass the pattern that you don't want in `list.files` arguments ?

Comment: Yes I would like to pass the unwanted pattern to be passed as `list.files` argument.

Comment: I hope [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590730/list-files-in-r-that-do-not-match-a-pattern) can helps you.