# Regex with this pattern AND that pattern

Tags: r, regex

Regex has a character for `or` but what is the character for `and`?

For example, say I have a folder with the following files:

```
list.files(path = 'example')
# [1] "abc_clean.csv"           "abc_other_clean.csv"     "abc_other_raw.csv"      
# [4] "abc_raw.csv"             "abc_something_clean.csv" "abc_something_raw.csv"  
# [7] "def_clean.csv"           "def_other_clean.csv"     "def_other_raw.csv"      
# [10] "def_raw.csv"             "def_something_clean.csv" "def_something_raw.csv"
```

And I want to match the files that both have `abc' and 'clean'. None of these work:

```
> list.files(path = 'example', pattern = 'abc')
[1] "abc_clean.csv"           "abc_other_clean.csv"     "abc_other_raw.csv"      
[4] "abc_raw.csv"             "abc_something_clean.csv" "abc_something_raw.csv"  

> list.files(path = 'example', pattern = 'clean')
[1] "abc_clean.csv"           "abc_other_clean.csv"     "abc_something_clean.csv"
[4] "def_clean.csv"           "def_other_clean.csv"     "def_something_clean.csv"

> list.files(path = 'example', pattern = 'abc*clean')
character(0)

> list.files(path = 'example', pattern = '[abc][clean]')
[1] "abc_clean.csv"           "abc_other_clean.csv"     "abc_other_raw.csv"      
[4] "abc_raw.csv"             "abc_something_clean.csv" "abc_something_raw.csv"  
[7] "def_clean.csv"           "def_other_clean.csv"     "def_something_clean.csv"
```

For this example, the result I would like is something like:

```
[1] "abc_clean.csv"           "abc_other_clean.csv"     "abc_something_clean.csv"
```

And please note that this is not about the specific case of listing files. It's not the first time I've tried to get an `and` on a regex and got confused.

**data**

```
x <- c("abc_clean.csv", "abc_other_clean.csv", "abc_other_raw.csv", "abc_raw.csv",
       "abc_something_clean.csv", "abc_something_raw.csv", "def_clean.csv",
       "def_other_clean.csv", "def_other_raw.csv", "def_raw.csv", "def_something_clean.csv",
       "def_something_raw.csv")
```

Comment: Related / dupe [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just allow any character between? `abc.*clean.*`

If you need expect different order, how about use OR: `abc.*clean.*|clean.*abc.*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8UXrVB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?=.*abc)(?=.*clean).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iiA6rv/1)

Comment: Since the `list.files` function doesn't seem to support perl, they'd probably do as seen here with the R code around the pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590908

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on R: `> list.files(path = 'example', pattern = regex('^(?=.*abc)(?=.*clean).*$'))
Error in list.files(path = "example", pattern = regex("^(?=.*abc)(?=.*clean).*$")) : 
  invalid 'pattern' regular expression`